# Клиент-серверное приложение работающее с виртуальной локальной сетью. C#

Tags: c#, сеть, клиент-сервер, wcf, сетевое-программирование

Недавно заинтересовался вопросом как работает "локальный хост" в играх. Допустим есть два компьютера в локальной сети, на одном приложение делает хост, а на другом его (хост) обнаруживает. Причем это работает не только в настоящей локальной сети, но и через виртуальную (эмуляторы по типу Hamachi, Radmin VPN и др.).

В сущности вопрос в следующем - как приложение определяет ip хоста?
Я находил много примеров реализации клиент-серверных приложений, где заранее указывается адрес хоста, и конект к этому адресу. Но в описанном выше случае программа ведь сама устанавливает, находит и определяет нужные адреса.
Я могу просмотреть все потенциальные адреса вот так:

```cs
    NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
    foreach (var adapter in interfaces)
    {
          var ipProps = adapter.GetIPProperties();
    
          foreach (var ip in ipProps.UnicastAddresses)
          {
               if ((adapter.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                    && (ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    && adapter.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback)
               {
                       Console.WriteLine(ip.Address.ToString() + "|" + adapter.Description.ToString());
               }
          }
    }
```

### Догадка к решению проблемы

Возможно нужно сделать так: получить адрес сети, и попробовать пропинговать все возможные адреса в этой сети, соответственно так мы вроде как должны найти сервер. Правильна ли догадка? А если так, то нужно делать хост на **0.0.0.0**? Может для этого использовать **WCF**? И если да, то подскажите что именно мне нужно почитать.

Comment: Сервер отправляет [широковещательный](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81) пакет (broadcast), клиенты его видят и отвечают серверу, сервер устанавливает соединение с ответившими клиентами. Никто никого не сканирует.

Comment: Второй сценарий: новый клиент отправляет широковещательный пакет, сервер его видит, отвечает клиенту и устанавливает с ним соединение.

Comment: @aepot То есть это сделать с помощью широковещательной рассылки? Получается нужно использовать UDP, а значит сервера как бы нет. Или я что то не так понял?

Comment: Как связано наличие сервера и UDP? Вы можете слушать UDP на сервере, а с клиента отправлять широковещательный пакет "Сервер, отзовись!", скажем, раз в 2 секунды. Задача через широковещаение услышать клиента и ответить ему пакетом с адресом себя и портом, после чего клиент установит нормальное TCP соединение сервером уже зная его адрес и порт. Вы можете подойти твоерчески к вопросу и реализовать так как считаете нужным, я всего-лишь подсказал технологию. Можно вообще всё на базе UDP сделать, здесь уж как вам больше нравится.